# Kevin Bacon path in Java gives a stack overflow?

Tags: java, stack-overflow, shortest-path

I'm pretty new to Java and I have a problem in my code, where I want to find the shortest path from *actor to movie to actor to movie to Kevin Bacon*. This is stored in a `list` which would go `"Actor A, Movie A, Actor B, Movie B, Kevin Bacon"`. I thought that the best way of doing this would be to do it `recursively`. However, I am getting a `StackOverflowError`.

I store the *actors* and *movies* in a `HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>`. Both *actors* and *movies* are `keys` - if the *actor* is called, then it returns a `HashSet` of the *movies* the *actor* has been in, and if the *movie* is called, it returns a `HashSet` of the *actors* it has. The `findCostars` method finds all the *actors* a given *actor* has costarred with.

Here is my code. Any help would be seriously appreciated!

```
public List<String> findBaconPath (String actor) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    ArrayList<String> actors = new ArrayList<String>();
    actors.add(actor);
    ArrayList<String> path = helper(actors, actor);
    return path;
}

public ArrayList<String> helper(ArrayList<String> curr, String actor) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashSet<String> movies = myMovies.get(actor);
    ArrayList<String> coStars = (ArrayList<String>) findCostars(actor);
    Iterator<String> it = movies.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String next = it.next();
        HashSet<String> movAct = myMovies.get(next);
        if (movAct.contains("Bacon, Kevin")) {
            list.add("Bacon, Kevin");
            list.add(next);
            list.add(actor);
            return list;
        } else {
            Iterator<String> itAct = coStars.iterator();
            while(itAct.hasNext()) {
                curr.add(next);
                String nextActorValue = itAct.next();
                curr.add(nextActorValue);
                helper(curr, nextActorValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you want shortest path or path that minimizes the sum of rottentomatoes ratings?  If the latter, you might want to be careful around net-negative loops involving *Tremors*'s sequels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a stack overflow because your search is depth-first, and you don't exclude the graph nodes you've already visited.

Since you probably want the shortest path, try implementing [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Comment: Hmm thanks! How do I go about marking the actors I've already visited? Since all I have is a hashmap that stores a string and a hashset, is a way to mark nodes that are already visited?

Comment: Because the tagging is temporary data specific to your algorithm, you don't want to litter the persistent movie/actor info with it. You can create a temporary hashset of visited nodes for the duration of your search.

Answer (score 0):

You never check that you don't process the same movie two times.

The first invocation will begin processing `movies`, the first iteration will likely call the same method for the first actor and the same movies. Then the second invocation will start iterating again over `movies`....